# cannot change datepicker date when minDate or beforeShowDay is used

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I had a datepicker in my page and everything worked.

Now I need to remove the sundays and to start the date from today. I made some search and I added this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,                     
        beforeShowDay: noSunday                 
});

function noSunday(date){
       var day = date.getDay();
       return [(day > 0), ''];
};
```

It happens that the user cannot select sundays and past days and this is correct; but when the chose a day, then it is always show: 12/gg/aa (12 is the month,gg stands for dd and aa stands for yy).

I don't know if it can be useful, but if I do not add the previous code, the date format is dd/mm/yy (gg/mm/aa)

any idea?

Comment: seems to work fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/ZKcAA/  Don't understand the format issues you mention

Comment: If I add the code, the format becomes mm/dd/yy. If I remove the code, the format is dd/mm/yy. I don't know if it can suggest something...

Comment: so what is different in my demo than your page?

Comment: you want to exclude only sundays? or weekend?

Comment: nothing is different in that part of the code...

only sunday, but the code works. The problem is after you select the date.